# Migrating from Hibernate 3.6.3 to 4.3.10 using liquibase changelog

Tags: hibernate, liquibase

Between Hibernate 3.6.3 and 4.3.10 the naming schema of the unique key constraints have changed. We are using liquibase to manage our database changes.

This has required us to add hundreds of constraint changes by hand like this:

```
<dropUniqueConstraint constraintName="attachednetworkdevicejpa_uuid_macaddress_vlan_key" tableName="attachednetworkdevicejpa"/>
<addUniqueConstraint columnNames="uuid, macaddress, vlan" constraintName="uk_2o0nn8nq8eoo40bpyyq5k9anh" deferrable="false" disabled="false" initiallyDeferred="false" tableName="attachednetworkdevicejpa"/>
```

I'm adopting this branch that has fallen far behind master and has tons of these new constraints that have to be added. Is there a better way to handle this or do these all need to be created by hand to support this migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up solving this by writing a python script to scrape the base changelog and the existing code and creating a migration change between the two.

The project can be found here:
https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/Hibernate-3-to-4-Liquibase-Changelog-Gen